# Best practice for storing and searching strings mysql

Tags: mysql, string, indexing

I have a table with, let's say, city names. Some have accents, spaces, hyphens, small caps, uppercases, etc...

On the other side, I have a search engine.

What is the best and fastest way to store the city names ?

Knowing that if someone is searching "**Saint-Locdu-Le-Vieux**" or "**saint-locdu-le-vieux**" or "**Saint Locdu Le Vieux**" or "**Saînt-Locdu-Lé-Vièux**", it will always match the same record.

I thought of having 2 columns, one for display, another one for searching with index where the city name would be stored as "SAINTLOCDULEVIEUX".

Maybe there is a feature I don't know of or a better way to do it ?

Thanks for reading :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware there isn't a native MySQL feature for this. What I would recommend if you're using MySQL for this is probably to have two columns: the "display" column that shows the accented and punctuated string, that is only useful for showing to a user, and a formatted "lookup" column, for example "saint locdu le vieux". Lookups of it could then be done by formatting and string-replacing input characters with accents to their non-accented equivalents, hiphens with spaces, etc, and doing queries like:

input: 'Saint-Locdu-'

query:

`SELECT * FROM City Where name LIKE '%saint locdu%';`

This of course is not an ideal solution. Lookups like this if you want to do them the cannonical way are best suited to a data structure and query engine like [solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/), that is typo-resistant and forgiving of characters not being quite right. However, I appreciate this isn't your question, I just thought I'd add it as a footnote.